# Паттерн Repository и MVVM. Как правильно связать модели?

Tags: c#, mvvm, repository, mvvm-light

Имеем модели:

```
public class EmployeeFunction{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class Employee 
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Code {get; set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public EmployeeFunction EmployeeFunction{get;set;}
}
```

Для моделей имеем реализацию репозиториев:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
//... 
}


public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepository<T>{
    //...
}

public class EmployeesRepository<Employee> {
    //...
}

public class EmployeeFunctionsRepository<EmployeeFunction> {
    //...
}
```

Используя **MVVM Light Toolkit** репозитории инжектятся во ViewModel.

```
public class EmployeesViewModel{
    //...
    private IRepository<Employee> _repository;
    public ObservableColeection<Emolyee> Items { get; private set; }

    public EmployeesViewModel(IRepository<Employee> repository){
        _repository = repository;
        Items = _repository.GetAll();
    }
    //...
}
```

Каким образом, при таком подходе, заполняется  свойство `EmployeeFunction` в классе `Employee`? Я так понимаю, что там должна храниться ссылка на инстанс `EmployeeFunction`, полученная из соответсвующего репозитория. Т.е. репозиторий сотрудников должен дергать репозиторий должностей чтобы получить необходимую ссылку?

Comment: MVVM тут не причем. Вы столкнулись  с типичной проблемой ответственности репозитория, а именно " что если репозиторию нужно дернуть метод другого репозитория". Должен ли он дергать или же сам собрать весь граф объектов.

Comment: @vitidev И как по Вашему будет более правильно? К примеру, если класс состоит в основном из ссылок на другие классы?

Comment: На этот вопрос нет идеального решения. http://blog.byndyu.ru/2011/08/repository.html В чем то придется жертвовать.ВСЕ варианты решения обладают какими то недостатками, увы. Я же, если уже есть репы, то рождаю класс ЧоТоТамQuery, то есть QueryObject который примет внутри себя сколько ему надо репозиториев и соберет нужный граф.

Comment: @vitidev Хм. Спасибо за наводку. Как-то с ходу даже в голову не пришло.